# Restringir vídeos do Vimeo para apenas meu site

Tags: php, api

É possivel fazer uma conta *premium* no Vimeo, enviar meus vídeos, restringir o acesso para ninguém visualizar eles no site do Vimeo, e mostrá-los apenas para clientes logados em meu site?

Existe uma API do Vimeo para isto? Procurei por algo parecido mais não achei nada.

Comment: Isso é configurado de maneira global ou individualmente a cada vídeo no próprio site Vimeo. Não sei se tem API pra isso, mas é feito facilmente usando a interface do site.

Answer (score 3):

Assim como o @brasofilo [disse nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28121/restringir-v%c3%addeos-do-vimeo-para-apenas-meu-site#comment52432_28121) isso pode ser feito pela interface do [site mesmo](http://vimeo.com/help/faq/managing-your-videos/privacy-settings#what-do-the-different-privacy-settings-do).

Ou através da API, usando o método **`vimeo.videos.embed.setPrivacy`**:

[image]

Ou seja, precisa passar o OAuth, o ID do vídeo, o nível de privacidade desejada e quais domínios podem mostrar o vídeo (por JSON).
[Veja a documentação oficial](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods/vimeo.videos.embed.setPrivacy).